# Connecting Lights to a 12/2 20 Amp Circuit

Tags: lighting

I am adding some new led can lights and I want to tap into a 12/2 20 amp circuit that is readily available. Would this be frowned upon because the can lights are daisy chained together via 14/2? Is there a workaround for this or something else I can do? There are not really any readily available 14/2 circuits. I am having a hard time justifying why this is a problem because you can certainly plug cords into outlets that aren't 12/2 or better.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question: let's see what our pros say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Do the 14/2 wires that connect the cans go through the attic?

Comment: Is the 14/2 wire *part of the "can lights" as they are manufactured*?  Can you link the product?   You can [edit] your question to add the info.

Comment: Can you add a small breaker panel at the tapping point?

Comment: If you run 14/2 on a 20amp circuit you MUST downgrade the breaker to 15amp.  Breaker size is always determined by the smallest wire used in the circuit.  If you want to keep the circuit at 20 amp, you must not add 14 gauge wire (internal fixture wiring itself is a different rule).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have this sense that there's something in the tap rules that might be relevant here...

Answer (score 2):

The wiring for the circuit (cable or individual wires in conduit, through walls, etc.) needs to all be protected by the circuit breaker. Any/all of that wire could *at some unpredictable time in the future* be used to the full capacity of the circuit - i.e., 20 A - and so it needs to all be big enough to handle the load. **You** are only putting in very low-current LED lights, but someone in the future might say "*Oh, a 20 Amp circuit! I don't need the lights so I'll bypass the lights (take out lights and splice properly in the junction boxes) and use the cable at the far end to power by 20A device.*" And then proceeds to wire up a 20A-rated device that pulls 16A continuously and overheats the 14 AWG wire.

The *external* wiring is different. The thin cord plugged in to power a device (lamp, tool, charger, whatever) is rated to handle the current needed **by the device**. Unless someone starts messing around with the device - e.g., taking the cord off to use it power something else - the cord should never have any current beyond the rated current for the device. If it has a short-circuit situation (== device failure) then the breaker should trip before any of the wiring burns up.

In addition, the external cord has air circulating around it. That is a bit different from a cable stuck in the wall. Related: [Never use an extension cord while it is coiled up](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192923/why-is-it-dangerous-use-a-coiled-extension-cord)